# How can I run a program from python on a file that is in-memory?

Tags: python, elf, file-descriptor

I am processing thousands of binaries wrapped in zip-like file containers, pulled from a remote database.  I need to analyze the contents of these binaries with tools like readelf, but I want to avoid incurring unnecessary IO to write the binaries to disk.

Is there a way to invoke subprocess.Popen so that I can pass the in-memory file to the command-line utility that the command would understand as being a file? I've tried assigning the file descriptor to stdin, but the utilities don't read the file contents from stdin as expected.

```
with zipfile.ZipFile(file,'r') as z:
  with z.open(binary_path) as bin:
    subprocess.Popen(['readelf','-d'],stdin=bin)
```

I've also tried directly setting the necessary argument to a reference to the file descriptor, but that's also proven fruitless:

```
with zipfile.ZipFile(file,'r') as z:
  with z.open(binary_path) as bin:
    subprocess.Popen(['readelf','-d',bin])
```

Is what I'm attempting possible, or should I just resort to writing to disk and analyzing from there?

Much thanks!

Comment: can't you write the contents of `bin` to a temporary file on disk ? Alternatively, can you use a RAM disk (if performance is an issue) ?

Comment: @AndreHolzner: He says right in the first paragraph that he doesn't want to write the binaries to disk. He may be wrong that this is a real cost (or he may just need to find a better way to do it), but he's clearly considered the basic idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zeroth, why do you need to `popen` `readelf`, instead of using `libelf` or something similar? A quick search for ["elf" at PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3aaction=search&term=elf&submit=search) shows lots of possibilities. Have you looked them over?

First, on many platforms, all of the I/O will end up going through the cache, so it won't really slow you down, even if it does end up eventually flushing everything to disk just to delete it (which it may never do). Careful use of `mmap` can often help avoiding flushing to disk, but you may not even need it.

So really, I'd test it first and see if excessive I/O really is slowing you down. If not, stop worrying about it.

If you want to be sure there's no disk I/O (I'm assuming you've disabled all swap, because otherwise that idea is meaningless in the first place), the easiest solution is to create a temporary file that isn't actually backed to disk.

The easiest way to do that is to create a ramdisk, and just put the temporary files there.

Alternatively, most platforms have a way to create a temporary file that either is never backed to disk, or is only backed to disk if absolutely necessary. Unfortunately, I don't think any of the stdlib Python functions can do this, in which case you'll have to write platform-specific code for it.

If you do want to pass an arbitrary buffer to a tool as stdin, it's easy. But you have to know how to tell the tool to read stdin—often that means something like passing `-c` as an option or `-` as a fake filename, or sometimes just not passing any filenames. Read the manpage to see which. For example:

```
with zipfile.ZipFile(file,'r') as z:
    with z.open(binary_path) as bin:
        subprocess.Popen(['gzip','-dc'], stdin=bin)
```

Unfortunately, some tools won't work this way, often because they require a seekable file rather than just a stream. I believe `readelf` is one of them. So this option isn't available.

And passing an arbitrary fd to a tool requires the tool to have a way to take arbitrary fds instead of filenames, which most of them don't.

Comment: Thanks for your many useful comments! 
I've tried using pyelftools, but I'm working with ARM binaries, and I need to determine what libraries the file depends on, both of which don't appear to be supported by the module.  I've tried hacking in support, but I'm not well versed in the low-level coding required to make it work properly. I'll check out any other modules I might have missed to see if they're able to provide the functionality I need, but I've done a pretty good dredge of the internet to figure this out. SO is my last resort.

Comment: @JymmyZ: Most of the libraries seem to be pure-Python ELF parsers; maybe one that wraps `libelf` would have more functionality—or, if there isn't such a library, maybe using `Cython` or `ctypes` to talk to `libelf` directly? I haven't tried it myself, so that may turn out to be a nightmare (and if you've never done any `Cython` or `ctypes`, this may not be the best time to learn…), but it may be worth considering.